# probability from a betting game die roll

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is from a trading interview I have done recently and I wanted to get feedback on my response.

You are offered a betting game where we roll a die, if the die lands on 3 or above, you win £10,000, if it lands on below 3, you give me 10,000.  Do you take the bet? What is the maximum amount you pay for the bet?( I believe this is how they phrased it I forgot specifically), how many times do you play the game?

My answer was $10,000\times(\frac{4}{6})+(-10,000\times\frac{2}{6})=3333.33$ so this is the expected value of  the bet and the maximum you pay? and  you play this game millions of times so that due to the law of large numbers it should converge to the expected value and you will turn out positive. Is this the right approach to tackle this?

Comment: Sounds correct (not sure if this q should be here though .. ).

Comment: You seem to have omitted some important considerations. What do you do if you only have £9000 to your name? (or at least that can be quickly accessed without substantial cost to you) -- you couldn't pay up on the first bet if it went against you. So to take the bet even a few times you require a large enough bankroll (enough reasonably liquid capital) that you don't ruin yourself before you make money.